# Как сделать подпись у иконки в floating action button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design

У меня есть Floating Action Button с Vector Drawable внутри. Можно ли под него вставить текст? (не рядом с кнопкой, а внутри нее, как на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671196/floatingactionbutton-with-text-instead-of-image

Comment: Самый простой вариант - добавить надпись прямо в векторную картинку.

Comment: именно текст на картинке тоже картинка - он нарисован, а не написан

Answer (score 2):

Действительно в таком варианте самый очевидный и простой способ это нарисовать текст. Те ваш текст это и есть вектор. 
Плюсов много, но ести и минусы -> локализация. Если это для вас не критично, то смело создавайте такие VectorDrawable всё будет отлично работать. Если вы всетаки, хотите вставлять отдельно любой текст менять его, то можно сделать например так:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera_white_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="Story"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это будет работать, но минусов тоже хватает, вы должны следить за размером текста, за размером картинки, в теории это можно довести до более хорошего решения, и не забывайте что android:elevation="16dp" необходим, иначе текст будет под FAB.

- Можно переопределить FAB и onDraw и дорисовывать текст на Canvas, такой вариант имеет место быть.

Comment: А что за метод с onDraw и Canvas? Можно подробнее про него?

Comment: это очень большая и интеерсная тема, если вы задаетесь этим вопросом, лучше  отложить на отдельное изучение, Вкратце вы можете на любой View нарисовать что вы хотите, и даже есть метод который рисует текст. Но лучше отдельно почитать. Android Canvas. В сети огромное количество уроков даже на ру, по этой теме.

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep можете посмотреть пример совмещения картинок и текста на своих кастомных View, например, в этом репозитории https://github.com/StanleyDevelop/RedGreyControlsCollection и, например, конкретно у реализации этого вью https://github.com/StanleyDevelop/RedGreyControlsCollection/blob/master/java/stan/rgcc/demo/ui/views/Switch.java - технически вашу задачу несложно реализовать одним маленьким классом, так не будет ни проблем с локализацией ни с размерами. Если интересно, могу попробовать подробно описать в ответе.

Comment: @StanleyWintergreen, если не трудно, то опишите. Зарание спасибо.